# selectizeInput in R shiny

Tags: r

I do R shiny project and in ui.R I have this code:

ui.R

```
    tabPanel("Ctree",  fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    selectizeInput("ctreeinput","Zvolte atributy k cielovemu atributu LoanAmount",choices=colnames(stats_people),multiple=TRUE),
    mainPanel(tableOutput("ctree1"))
    )
 ))
```

server.R

```
output$ctree1<- renderTable({  
set.seed(123)
library(party)

myFormula = LoanAmount_1 ~ input$ctreeinput

ctree = ctree(myFormula, data=train.ctree)
table(predict(ctree), train.ctree$LoanAmount_1)

ctreePred = predict(ctree, newdata = test.ctree)
table(ctreePred, test.ctree$LoanAmount_1)
})
```

In server.R I have myFormula, where I want to create something like this:

```
myFormula = LoanAmount ~ ApplicantIncome+CoapplicantIncome+Dependents+Gender+Married
```

... but it must be create by user. I want to use selectizeInput. This solution, what I paste here, it doesn´t work, RStudio says, that ERROR: object 'input' not found. What should I do to work my code? Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to  eval(parse(text = paste0("y~", paste(input$x1, input$x2,..., sep="+")))) ?

Comment: Don´t work for me, because I don´t know how many inputs will there.

Answer (score 0):

In server.R, before defining `myFormula`, you need to define an object (for instance, dataframe) named `input`, along with a sub-object (e.g., column) named `ctreeinput`.

Comment: How can I do it?